# Encrypting home folder without filename encryption using `ecryptfs`

Tags: filenames, encryption, home, ecryptfs

`ecryptfs` encrypts home folders with filename encryption by default. However, because of this, filenames with more than 143 characters can not exist in the home folder (while an unencrypted `ext4` home folder offers 255 character limit). If the filename encryption is disabled, the character limit is back to the default 255.

I had done the encryption of my home folder after installing the new Ubuntu 20.04 using the command `ecryptfs-migrate-home`, however many of the files failed to migrate because of this character limit.

How can I run the command `ecryptfs-migrate-home` with filename encryption **disabled**?

Answer (score 2):

One solution to do this is by modifying the `ecryptfs-migrate-home` script itself  which resides in `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-migrate-home`.

This script uses the command `ecryptfs-setup-private` to do the encryption, and we can pass it the `--no-fnek` option to disable the filename encryption.

Hence, on the line where the final encryption is done, add the `--no-fnek` option and you're done. Depending on your version, it should look something like this:

```shell
if ! ecryptfs-setup-private --no-fnek -u "$USER_NAME" -b $ECRYPTFS_SETUP_PRIVATE_ARGS
```

Comment: I can confirm that I tried this on Ubuntu 18 and it worked without any problems.